# Errbot: How to properly configure new plugins?

Tags: python-3.x, hipchat, errbot, chatops

I'm trying to follow the Errbot guide to create a new HelloWorld plugin. However, after my errbot has successfully connected to HipChat, I am unable to see the new plugin that I created. This is the DEBUG output from the console.

```
16:44:02 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma storage search paths {'/home/eugine/errbot-root/plugins/learning', '/home/eugine/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/storage', '/home/eugine/errbot-root/plugins/err-example'}
16:44:02 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma Found those plugings available:
16:44:02 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma     Helloworld  (/home/eugine/errbot-root/plugins/learning/helloworld.py)
16:44:02 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma          Shelf  (/home/eugine/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/storage/shelf.py)
16:44:02 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma         Memory  (/home/eugine/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/storage/memory.py)
16:44:02 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma        Example  (/home/eugine/errbot-root/plugins/err-example/example.py)
16:44:02 INFO     errbot.bootstrap          Found Storage plugin: 'Shelf'
Description: This is the storage plugin for the traditional shelf store for errbot.
16:44:02 DEBUG    errbot.specific_plugin_ma Refilter the plugins...
16:44:02 WARNING  yapsy                     Plugin candidate '/home/eugine/errbot-root/plugins/learning/helloworld.plug'  rejected by strategy 'SpecificBackendLocator'
16:44:02 WARNING  yapsy                     Plugin candidate '/home/eugine/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/storage/memory.plug'  rejected by strategy 'SpecificBackendLocator'
16:44:02 WARNING  yapsy                     Plugin candidate '/home/eugine/errbot-root/plugins/err-example/example.plug'  rejected by strategy 'SpecificBackendLocator'
16:44:02 DEBUG    errbot.specific_plugin_ma Load the one remaining...
16:44:02 DEBUG    errbot.specific_plugin_ma Class to load ShelfStoragePlugin
16:44:02 DEBUG    errbot.storage            Opening storage 'repomgr'
16:44:02 DEBUG    errbot.storage.shelf      Open shelf storage /home/eugine/errbot-root/data/repomgr.db
16:44:02 DEBUG    errbot.storage            Opening storage 'core'
16:44:02 DEBUG    errbot.storage.shelf      Open shelf storage /home/eugine/errbot-root/data/core.db
```

This is the output from typing "!status" in the private chat with the bot.

```
Yes I am alive...
```

Plugins

┏━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Status ┃ Name           ┃
┡━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ A      │ ACLs           │
├────────┼────────────────┤
│ A      │ Backup         │
├────────┼────────────────┤
│ A      │ ChatRoom       │
├────────┼────────────────┤
│ A      │ Flows          │
├────────┼────────────────┤
│ A      │ Health         │
├────────┼────────────────┤
│ A      │ Help           │
├────────┼────────────────┤
│ A      │ Plugins        │
├────────┼────────────────┤
│ A      │ Utils          │
├────────┼────────────────┤
│ A      │ VersionChecker │
├────────┼────────────────┤
│ C      │ Webserver      │
└────────┴────────────────┘
 A = Activated, D = Deactivated, B = Blacklisted, C = Needs to be configured
 Load 0.02, 0.01, 0.0
GC 0->211 1->0 2->4

I have looked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486120/errbot-getting-yapsy-error-when-trying-to-configure-plugins-via-command-line-in) but it hasn't been very helpful.

Here is the code for helloworld.py

```
from errbot import BotPlugin, botcmd, arg_botcmd, webhook
```

class Helloworld(BotPlugin):
    """
    Hello world and other testing and learning
    """

```
def activate(self):
    """
    Triggers on plugin activation

    You should delete it if you're not using it to override any default behaviour
    """
    super(Helloworld, self).activate()

def deactivate(self):
    """
    Triggers on plugin deactivation

    You should delete it if you're not using it to override any default behaviour
    """
    super(Helloworld, self).deactivate()

def get_configuration_template(self):
    """
    Defines the configuration structure this plugin supports

    You should delete it if your plugin doesn't use any configuration like this
    """
    return {'EXAMPLE_KEY_1': "Example value",
            'EXAMPLE_KEY_2': ["Example", "Value"]
           }

def check_configuration(self, configuration):
    """
    Triggers when the configuration is checked, shortly before activation

    Raise a errbot.utils.ValidationException in case of an error

    You should delete it if you're not using it to override any default behaviour
    """
    super(Helloworld, self).check_configuration(configuration)

def callback_connect(self):
    """
    Triggers when bot is connected

    You should delete it if you're not using it to override any default behaviour
    """
    pass

def callback_message(self, message):
    """
    Triggered for every received message that isn't coming from the bot itself

    You should delete it if you're not using it to override any default behaviour
    """
    pass

def callback_botmessage(self, message):
    """
    Triggered for every message that comes from the bot itself

    You should delete it if you're not using it to override any default behaviour
    """
    pass

@webhook
def example_webhook(self, incoming_request):
    """A webhook which simply returns 'Example'"""
    return "Example"

# Passing split_args_with=None will cause arguments to be split on any kind
# of whitespace, just like Python's split() does
@botcmd(split_args_with=None)
def example(self, message, args):
    """A command which simply returns 'Example'"""
    return "Example"

@arg_botcmd('name', type=str)
@arg_botcmd('--favorite-number', type=int, unpack_args=False)
def hello(self, message, args):
    """
    A command which says hello to someone.

    If you include --favorite-number, it will also tell you their
    favorite number.
    """
    return "Hello, " + format(msg.frm)
```

This is the code for helloworld.plug

```
[Core]
module = helloworld
name = Helloworld

[Documentation]
description = Hello world and other testing and learning

[Python]
version = 3

[Errbot]
min = 4.3.7
max = 4.3.7
```

These have been generated by using the command line `errbot --new-plugin`

Any pointers will be much appreciated!

Comment: It might be that you have generated the plugin at the wrong spot ? Can you give us the config of errbot (remove the credentials) and the path of your plugin ?

Comment: @gbin Looks like BOT_EXTRA_PLUGIN_DIR was set to none. I thought BOT_EXTRA_STORAGE_PLUGINS_DIR needed to be set. Helloworld now shows up in !status. Thank you!